# Find function TO_DATE oracle in QGIS

Tags: sql, oracle, qgis

In QGIS I get an error (to_date function error), can you tell me why?`

If it's impossible, what can we replace it with?

```
TO_DATE(t.DATE_TOURNEE,'DD/MM/YYYY') as DATE_TOURNEE
```

Comment: Probably the string is not in the right format.  Provide sample data and explain the error.

Comment: Hello
and thank you for your answer, the elements in the cell look like this
"2018-06-22T02: 00: 00.000" and the identity of the field and in "string" format

Comment: How do you expect anyone to tell you why you get an error when you don't tell what the error is?  I'll tell you that if t.DATE_TOURNEE is of type DATE, then you shouldn't even be using to_date at all.  to_date takes a STRING, not a DATE as input.

Comment: Does "2018-06-22T02: 00: 00.000" look like it is the format 'DD/MM/YYYY', which you specified in your TO_DATE call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below function,

```
to_date(substr(t.DATE_TOURNEE, 0, instr(t.DATE_TOURNEE, '.')-1), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24: mi: ss')
```

Demo
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f595387b2bc649dbf1a07453a0593baf

Comment: Hi
Indeed, I used this formulaTO_DATE(SUBSTR(t.DATE_TOURNEE,0,10) ,’YYYY-MM-DD')

Answer (score 1):

`TO_DATE(text, format)..`  converts a particular format in default database standard format so the format expects the exact format that you have I.e. 2018-06-22T02: 00: 00.000 or
`YYYY-MM-DDTHH: MM.0SS`